# What is a first class persistence framework?

Tags: database, persistence, mybatis

I have been currently learning myBatis. The very first line of description for myBatis says that it is a first class persistence framework. Now I understand persistence reflects sending data in its most natural form to and from the database but I don't understand what the first class in the persistence frameworks stands for. I have searched net but haven't found any specific answer for that. Does anybody tell me what first class stands for?

Comment: Okay so there is no classification as such amongst the persistence framework?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It probably falls in line with the [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First-class_citizen) explanation  of first-class citizen below:

In programming language design, a first-class citizen (also object, entity, or value), in the context of a particular programming language, is an entity that can be constructed at run-time, passed as a parameter, returned from a subroutine, or assigned into a variable. In computer science the term reification is used when referring to the process (technique, mechanism) of making something a first-class object.